# Can't convert virtual machine from ESXi to Hyper-V 2012 R2

Tags: hyper-v

I have a VMWare ESXi 5.5 Server and a Hyper-V 2012 R2 Core server (called Lithium) in a WORKGROUP. My Windows 8.1 machine is in the same WORKGROUP. I am trying to convert a VM from the ESXi host to the Hyper-V host using Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter (MVMC).

I want the destination to be a share on the Hyper-V host called \Lithium\Machines. I have tested that my account has write permissoins to this share from my workstation but I get this error in MVMC

[image]

I created the share with this command on the Hyper-V host:

```
PS C:\Users\mark> new-smbshare -Name Machines -Path "C:\Users\Public\Documents\H
yper-V\Virtual Hard Disks" -FullAccess LITHIUM\Mark, LITHIUM\Administrator
```

and it was created fine:

```
PS C:\Users\mark> get-smbshare -name machines | ft -auto

Name     ScopeName Path                                                 Descrip
                                                                        tion
----     --------- ----                                                 -------
Machines *         C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you set the share permissions, but not the NTFS permissions. You need to do both.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's permissioned at the FS level too, but I'll check when I get home later. I have already tested I can write to the share with the account I'm logged in as, so it's a little odd. Will feed back, later.

Comment: Which user account are you using? Mark or Administrator?

Comment: I permissioned at the NTFS level and now all is well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vmware converter to do this, or you can used Disk2Vhd, Both tools will work. Using vmware converter you can directly send the VM on a network share partition. If you planning to use Disk2vhd, you must map a network drive or use an external disk to transfer the VM.

Hope that helps 
Rgs 
Sundeep seetloo

Answer (score -2):

MVMC  Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter seems to need vSphere and doesn't work with only ESXi servers

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977338 
 - (applies to MVMC but I think still the case for MVMC 3.0 and 3.1)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn873998.aspx claims

> Supports conversion of virtual machines from VMware vSphere 5.5, VMware vSphere 5.1, and VMware vSphere 4.1 hosts to Hyper-V

check the mvmc_engine.log and mvmc.log under %TEMP%

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to match the question.

Comment: sorry is a bit off but relevant to the google search results for the issue. let me know if I should remove it.

Comment: Yes, you should remove it. It's not relevant to the question.